# Can I restart a FAILED celery task?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I am using celery with the [djkombu](https://github.com/ask/django-kombu) queue.

I've set `max_retries=3` for my task. Once the 3rd retry fails, it executes the `after_return` method with `status=FAILURE`. The method also receives a `task_id` parameter. With this `task_id`, can I restart the task manually (I think I will need to set the `Message.visible` to 1) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-launch the task with the same args you launched it before.